# JavaScript functions do not reset without refreshing the page after new data is entered

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, graph

I am trying to display a graph using d3.js for which I take the data from the database according to the users input on my HTML, but when a new search with new input is initiated from the user without refreshing the page, the graph looses the functionalities. The graph is updated according to the new input, but the brush functionality and the update function do not work.
For the connection with the database I use PHP and the query result is saved in a variable `$jsonInput` that is encoded to JSON and after that used in this script. Here is my script:

```js
     var margin = { top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 130, left: 60 },
      width = 999 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var svg = d3
      .select("#input_viz")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    //svg.append("text")
      //.attr("class", "x-axis-title")
      //.attr("text-anchor", "right")
      //.attr("x", width)
      //.attr("y", height + margin.top + 15) // Adjust the y-coordinate to control the position
      //.text("Date");

    svg.append("text")
      .attr("class", "y-axis-title")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("x", -height / 2)
      .attr("y", -margin.left + 20) // Adjust the y-coordinate to control the position
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .text("Traffic (Mbps)");

    var data = [ ["2023-08-03 13:30:04", 849], ["2023-08-03 13:15:04", 815], ["2023-08-03 13:00:04", 755], ["2023-08-03 12:45:04", 643], ["2023-08-03 12:30:04", 704], ["2023-08-03 12:15:03", 656], ["2023-08-03 12:00:03", 711], ["2023-08-03 11:45:03", 664], ["2023-08-03 11:30:03", 652], ["2023-08-03 11:15:04", 683] ]

    var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");

    data.forEach(function (d) {
      d.date = parseDate(d[0]);
      d.value = +d[1];
    });

    var customTimeFormat = d3.timeFormat("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S");

    var x = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.date; }))
      .range([0, width]);
    var xAxis = svg.append("g")
      .attr('class','xAxis')
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    xAxis.call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(customTimeFormat))
      .selectAll("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("dx", "-1em")
      .attr("dy", "-0.5em")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)");

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.value; })])
      .range([height, 0]);
    var yAxis = svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(20));

    var clip = svg.append("defs").append("svg:clipPath")
      .attr("id", "clip")
      .append("svg:rect")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", 0);

    var brush = d3.brushX()
      .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
      .on("end", updateChart);

    var area = svg.append('g')
      .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

    var areaGenerator = d3.area()
      .x(function (d) { return x(d.date); })
      .y0(y(0))
      .y1(function (d) { return y(d.value); });

    area.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "myArea")
      .attr("fill", "#228B22")
      .attr("fill-opacity", .6)
      .attr("stroke", "#228B22")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1)
      .attr("d", areaGenerator);

    area.append("g")
      .attr("class", "brush")
      .call(brush);

    var idleTimeout;

    function idled() {
      idleTimeout = null;
    }

    function updateChart({selection}) {
      // What are the selected boundaries?
      extent = selection;

      if (!extent) {
        if (!idleTimeout) return idleTimeout = setTimeout(idled, 350);
        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.date; }));
      } else {
        x.domain([x.invert(extent[0]), x.invert(extent[1])]);
        area.select(".brush").call(brush.move, null);
      }

    xAxis.transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(customTimeFormat))
        .selectAll("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-1em")
        .attr("dy", "-0.5em")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)");
      area
        .select('.myArea')
        .transition()
        .duration(1000)
        .attr("d", areaGenerator);
    }

    svg.on("dblclick", function () {
      x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.date; }));

    xAxis
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(customTimeFormat))
        .selectAll("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-1em")
        .attr("dy", "-0.5em")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)");
      area
        .select('.myArea')
        .transition()
        .attr("d", areaGenerator);
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8"/>  
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title> 1.Grundgerüst </title>    
    <style>

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="input_viz"></div>


<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I want the script to have all the functionalities if a new search is initiated, without having the need to refresh the page.

Comment: As of now I'd guess that the problem is the `if (!idleTimeout) return ...` line inside `updateChart` which skips the rest of the function whenever `idleTimeout` has a value that can be casted to a boolean `false` (like `undefined`, `null`, etc.). Besides: What is the intended purpose of that line?

Comment: The purpose of that mechanism is to delay certain actions until the user has stopped interacting with the chart, but even if I remove that part it does not resolve the issue that I am facing.

Answer (score 0):

i created a Snipped with your code.

I added `updateChartData` function that you can call with new data to update your graph

I also added

```
updateChartData(data);

d3.interval(() => {
  updateChartData(data.map(e => [e[0], Math.round(Math.random() * 1000)]));
}, 5000)
```

At the end update your graph with random data every 5 sec.

Hope this help

```js
var margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 130,
    left: 60
  },
  width = 999 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3
  .select("#input_viz")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


svg.append("text")
  .attr("class", "y-axis-title")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("x", -height / 2)
  .attr("y", -margin.left + 20) // Adjust the y-coordinate to control the position
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .text("Traffic (Mbps)");

var data = [
  ["2023-08-03 13:30:04", 849],
  ["2023-08-03 13:15:04", 815],
  ["2023-08-03 13:00:04", 755],
  ["2023-08-03 12:45:04", 643],
  ["2023-08-03 12:30:04", 704],
  ["2023-08-03 12:15:03", 656],
  ["2023-08-03 12:00:03", 711],
  ["2023-08-03 11:45:03", 664],
  ["2023-08-03 11:30:03", 652],
  ["2023-08-03 11:15:04", 683]
]

var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");

var customTimeFormat = d3.timeFormat("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S");

var x = d3.scaleTime()
  .range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([height, 0]);
var xAxis = svg.append("g")
  .attr('class', 'xAxis')
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")

xAxis.call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(customTimeFormat))
  .selectAll("text")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("dx", "-1em")
  .attr("dy", "-0.5em")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)");

var yAxis = svg.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(20));

svg.append("defs").append("svg:clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("svg:rect")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", 0);

var brush = d3.brushX()
  .extent([
    [0, 0],
    [width, height]
  ])
  .on("end", updateChartZoom);

var area = svg.append('g')
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

var areaGenerator = d3.area()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.date);
  })
  .y0(y(0))
  .y1(function(d) {
    return y(d.value);
  });

area.append("path")
  .attr("class", "myArea")
  .attr("fill", "#228B22")
  .attr("fill-opacity", .6)
  .attr("stroke", "#228B22")
  .attr("stroke-width", 1)

area.append("g")
  .attr("class", "brush")

const updateChartData = (data) => {

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d[0]);
    d.value = +d[1];
  });
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d.date;
  }))

  xAxis.call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(customTimeFormat)).selectAll("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("dx", "-1em")
    .attr("dy", "-0.5em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)");


  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.value;
  })]);
  yAxis.call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(20));

  svg.select('.myArea').datum(data)
    .attr("d", areaGenerator);
  svg.select('.brush')
    .call(d3.brushX()
      .extent([
        [0, 0],
        [width, height]
      ])
      .on("end", updateChartZoom))
  svg.select('.brush')

}


function updateChartZoom({
  selection
}) {
  var extent = selection;

  if (extent) {
    x.domain([x.invert(extent[0]), x.invert(extent[1])]);
    area.select(".brush").call(brush.move, null);
  }

  xAxis.transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(customTimeFormat))
    .selectAll("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("dx", "-1em")
    .attr("dy", "-0.5em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)");
  area
    .select('.myArea')
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("d", areaGenerator);
}


svg.on("dblclick", function() {
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d.date;
  }));

  xAxis
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(customTimeFormat))
    .selectAll("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("dx", "-1em")
    .attr("dy", "-0.5em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)");
  area
    .select('.myArea')
    .transition()
    .attr("d", areaGenerator);
});

updateChartData(data);

d3.interval(() => {
  updateChartData(data.map(e => [e[0], Math.round(Math.random() * 1000)]));
}, 5000)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title> 1.Grundgerüst </title>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="input_viz"></div>


  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This did not solve the issue I am facing. To explain, the data contains the information of the traffic for a few nodes that I monitor and the date when that value is obtained. This info is stored on my database and whenever the user selects a specific node (A) on my html, the info from the database is received and after that shown in the graph. When the user selects another node (B) on the html, the graph updates according to the info received on the database for that node, but the graph looses the zoom function, unless I refresh the webpage.

Comment: But I do not want to refresh the webpage for every search because it automatically goes to my home page. This is not user-friendly, since from the home page I will need to go to the right section and after that start a new search for the next node. I hope I am clear enough what I am trying to reach.

Comment: If you make a REST endpoint to retrieve your data, you can fetch new data from hmlt/javascript (you can even use d3 `d3.json(url[, callback])` ) add call `updateChartData(newData)` with your new dataset.